# Elasticsearch - Filtering / Boosting based on a list of ids

Tags: performance, elasticsearch

i have user objects indexed with various fields in a ES index.
I also have another services (not ES) telling me which of my users are currently online. It's a simple list of user ids. I can't index this "is_online" field cause it changing too regularly.

But i'd like to be able to perfom various query using this online status.
For exemple, i'd like to be able to filter my results to get only users that are currently online.
But i'd also like to be able to perform boost query based on this list of ids.
For example, i'd like to be able to get a list of users, preferably thoose who are online.
I dont know what is the best way to do that (performance POV).

Any help is welcome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that a [Terms Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html) could help:

```
GET /_search
{
    "query" : {
        "terms" : {
            "user" : ["id1", "id2", "idn"]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok for filtering. But what about scoring ? I'd like to boost users wh are online. Any idea ? Thx you !

Comment: "constant_score" can be configured to give a boost value.  They basically wrap a filter so that a filter can contribute a score to the query.  See: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/constant-score-query.html